# Why if statement with innerWidth does not change it's behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code for the hamburger icon `'.navbar-toggle'` (for small screen) and logo icon (for bigger screen).cc

```
   if ($(window).innerWidth() > 768) {
      $('.navbar-toggle').click(function () {
          alert("wide screen");
      });
    } else { 
      $('.navbar-toggle').click(function () {
          alert("mobile");
      });
    }
```

- The desired behaviour is when the viewport/screen size is greater than 768px, I should see `alert("wide screen");`.

Which it does that. But when I resize the page without reload, and click again still get `alert("wide screen");` instead of `alert("mobile");`!!!

I want to know what is wrong with this code and if there is a better way to do that, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/117/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function () {
        if ($(window).innerWidth() > 768) {
            alert("wide screen");
        }
        else {
            alert("mobile");
        }
    });
});
```

the if statement is inside the onclick of the button/link.  what you were seeing before was the initial size of the screen (when the if statement was outside the click).  so onload of the page, the initial screen size was either wide screen or mobile, and even if you adjusted the width, it was still working off the initial width.  however, with this code, when the click event is triggered, it will check the current screen size and alert accordingly

Answer (score -1):

Removing the `$('.navbar-toggle')` parts, the logic works correctly.

I suspect this is because the code runs once, sees the window is large, and binds the first click handler. That handler is never unbound, even when the window is resized, so it will always be fired.

In real life, that behavior is probably fine, as most people will not resize their window and expect the UX to suddenly change. However, if you want to make the page properly responsive, you should watch for window resize events and (un)bind your handlers when that occurs.